# Akka - Getting info from terminated actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using Akka actors in Scala for parallel processing of queue items. I have a MasterActor with 10 reusable child ProcessorActors.

Items being processed can be of different types, e.g. red, blue & green items. At one moment of time, only a single item of some type can be processed. Thus, if one red item is being processed, no more reds can be processed at the same time.

All is fine but now I try to implemented good fault tolerance for the app and it turns out I can't get much info about what item type failed in Terminated message. If ProcessorActor fails, I need to mark appropriate type in MasterActor as available for processing. Right now I'm stuck as I just can't get what item type failed. I have an ActorRef in Terminated message but afaiu it's not good to send messages to it right after I get that message.

In the end I can be left with all possible types marked as "being processed" while in reality it's just their appropriate actors are dead.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I finally did and what seemed best. I set a Restart policy on `ProcessorActor` failure and handle `preRestart` method in it. If `reason:Option[Any]` is not empty and matches `StartProcessingMessage(Item(ItemType))` then I send a `ProcessingFailedMessage(Item(ItemType))` to `sender`. Supervisor actor then marks type as not processed and next `while` loop will initiate processing by some `ProcessorActor`, maybe even the one that failed and was just restarted.

Answer (score 1):

On `Terminated` set some 'pause' flag of not providing new jobs to children, then ping all `ProcessorActors` if they have active jobs, if any job can be assigned - assign job and release 'pause' flag. If terminated received when that 'pause' flag is set - do ping once more.

Comment: Ok but this does not solve the problem of identifying what job failed. How can I get concrete actor that is terminated? I have ActorRef in Terminated message but it doesn't allow to get real ProcessorActor by that reference.

Comment: I though the main design point was not to allow 2 green jobs at the same time. You could just count jobs on ping, and assign what's left - for example you have 1 blue 1 green 1 red. Blue failed and then green seems finished during Terminate handling - assign blue and green, ignore next message from green... Considering concrete `ProcessorActor` - you don't have in Akka, any concrete actors, especially remote ones - only references that communicate via messages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want to do could be achieved just by redesigning your architecture to have a red actor, a blue actor and a green actor, and setting the supervision strategy to do a restart on actor failure, instead of a stop. Really simple. No need to even handle the Termination message yourself.

Comment: Good option, though number of types is not predefined and will be changed while program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProcessorActor` can send a message (with type of the item) to `MasterActor` just before start processing the item. In your `MasterActor` you can maintain a `Map[ActorRef, ItemType]` using which you can determine by the `ActorRef` (received in the `Terminated` message) the last item type being processing when the `ProcessorActor` dies.